# Is Windows Phone 7 browser able to display silverlight applications

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible for the browser of Windows Phone 7 do display Silverlight websites?

If not, do you know if it will be possible in Mango?

Thanks and best regards,
Bruno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the IE browser doesn't support Silverlight websites - neither for WP7.0 nor for Mango (7.5)

Comment: Which is pretty paradoxical. Just accept application developed in Silverlight, doesn't render Silverlight in the web.